# How do I get rid of the browser scrollbar when opening images with fancybox?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Please check the following website [http://www.charbelnicolas.com](http://charbelnicolas.com)

When you open any of the images, the browser automatically displays the right scrollbar. How does one get rid of it?

It's annoying because the scrollbar shifts the images position and it is no longer centered and the scrollbar is greyed-out and really serves no purpose.

Any help is appreciated... I searched on google for an anwser and couldn't find it.

Thank you

Comment: I'm trying to use `helpers:  {
    overlay: {
        locked: false
    }
}` but I have no idea on how to mix it with the code I already have `<script type="text/javascript">
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(
    {
     helpers : {
      overlay : {
       css : {
        'background' : 'rgba(66, 90, 112, 0.95)'
        }
       }
      },
      
      closeBtn  : false,
      
      openEffect  : 'none',
      closeEffect : 'none',

      prevEffect : 'none',
      nextEffect : 'none',
      
      padding : 5
      
     }
    );
   });
   
        </script>`

Comment: your content shifts because your `body` has `absolute` position. Do you really need that?

Comment: Hello JFK, yes I need that so the page remains centered vertically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jquery.fancybox.css you will find this:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Change this to

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or override it from your stylesheet by adding this to style.css:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
   overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: @CharbelNicolas the problem with editing the original files is that if you upgrade, you have to do it again.